# How to make $.get call during form submission?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, forms, upload

I don't want to submit my form with AJAX, but I want to make a progress bar by making a couple of GET requests to the server during form submission, since the submission might take a while with multiple file uploads. I've found that in webkit browsers, I can't make GET requests while the form is submitting and I was seeing that submitting the form to an iframe would allow me to do it.

The markup looks like this:

```
<form action="/my-action" target="target-iframe">
...
</form>
<iframe name="target-iframe"></iframe>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function() {
    $.get("/other-action", function(data) {
      // Use data returned here
    });
  });
});
```

I'm still not getting data back on the GET request--how can I get this to work?

Comment: Everything looks good with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bUt4P/. Make sure your server is properly configured and you're requesting a correct URI.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) { //add a parameter e - the event object
     e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting
    $.get("/other-action", function(data) {
      // Use data returned here
    });
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

Set a flag that won't allow the form to submit until you've received your response form your get request. Once you've received your response, set your flag to allow your form to submit and then resubmit it programmatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canISubmit = false;
  $("form").on("submit", function(e) { //add a parameter e - the event object
     var el = $(this);
     if(!canISubmit) {
       e.preventDefault();


       $.get("/other-action", function(data) {
         canISubmit = true;
         el.submit();
       });
     }


  });
});
```

The only way to be certain that your `$.get` request was completed is to make sure that the form doesn't submit and redirect the page until your `$.get` request completes.

**EDIT #2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("form").on("submit", function(e) { //add a parameter e - the event object
     e.preventDefault();

     $.post("url",$(this).serialize())
        .done(function(response,status,jqXHR) {

            $.get("/other-action")
                .done(function(response,status,jqXHR) {
                    //other stuff done

                    //refresh the page or do whatever....
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    //$.get failed
                });

        })
        .fail(function() {
            //$.post failed
        });

  });

});
```

Comment: I want the $.get to occur while the form is submitting though, so I don't think preventDefault is what I want here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My problem is that the data that I'm getting is being set dynamically by the controller action being invoked by the form submission. So I need the form submission to kick off before I can make the get request, otherwise it won't be returning the right data. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: Yes - submit the form via a `$.post` request (not via the normal browser submission - so you'd still use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form from submitting). Then, when you get the response from the request, do your `$.get`

Comment: I'm uploading files so the `$.post` request gets tricky and I want the `$.get` to occur almost immediately after the form submission occurs, but before it completes, so I don't want to wait until I get the response back from the server.

Comment: I've given you everything you need to build this yourself.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but my problem still isn't solved because neither making the `$.get` request before submission nor making it after getting the response from the server are what I want. That's why I originally asked how to submit the form to an iframe so I could still make `$.get` requests **while** it's submitting--not before or after.